# I am not able to understand the output of the following code

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, append

I am not able to understand how this python code is working.

```
a=[0,1,2,3]
b=[]
for a[-1] in a:
       b.append(a[-1])
print(b)
```

The output for this code is `[0,1,2,2]`. I am not able to understand how this output is obtained. How the for loop is working here ?

Comment: Run with pdb:  python -m pdb script.py. Then you can see what happens in each step

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/